# What is OpenTok .NET API threading behavior?

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading, opentok

What is the threading behavior of the OpenTok Windows SDK (.NET)?
Are all these interfaces thread safe? (Can methods be called from multiple threads, potentially simultaneously?)
Are event handlers called in secondary threads or always the same thread or the user interface thread, or what?
The documentation says nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The opentok sdk is expected to be called from a single thread, it is not designed to be called from multiple threads simultaneously.

More precisely, methods should be invoked in the same thread where the `Context` instance is created. Since the `Context` object is a singleton, it is created the first time you call `Context.Intance`

The events are also invoked in the same thread as above.

However, there is just an exception to the rule above, when you are developing a WPF application, the events are always invoked in the Main Thread, for other types of application the events are called in the same thread you created the Context.

Typically the thread where you interact with the SDK and  where you get the events is the UI Thread, there is were you create `Session`, `Publisher` and `Subscriber` instances and where the events are invoked.

Comment: This does not appear to be correct for events. I created Context in the Main thread. If I break into event handlers, they are called on other threads.

Comment: Which version of the sdk are you using? Can you reproduce it with Basic Video Chat from the samples repo?

Comment: SDK is 2.16.6. The sample app seems to behave as you describe. However, the sample app is C#. I am using C++/CLI. This shouldn't make any difference, but somehow it does.